# Use Ajax to send data to external page, and then load said external page

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I have a thumbnail gallery populated from a database using php. Each thumbnail is also a link. What I would like is to be able to load an external php page in each case, with the large version of each thumbnail on it, flanked with related images.

The database tables are all set up properly in a relational sense, but I'm not sure about the functionality of being able to send data, in this case `imgId`, from the thumbnail gallery page, to the external page, and load the external page at the same time.

I thought it would be possible to do with a form submit, but since I need this functionality on every single thumbnail link, I thought that Ajax would work using jQuery. But alas it doesn't seem to be sending the data when I click on the link.

Hopefully someone can give me some advice. Thanks in advance.

**The HTML:**

```
<a target="_blank" href="secondary_imgs.php" class="gallery" value="16">
   <img src="new_arrivals_img/thumbnails/boss-skaz1_black_front.jpg">
</a>
```

**The jQuery:**

```
$('.gallery').click(function(){
    $.get("secondary_imgs.php", { imgId: $('.gallery').attr('value') });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I feel kinda stupid, but I figured out that all I needed to do was pass the data through the URL. The PHP code below shows what I mean, and I do thank those who helped me with this problem. My fault for making it faaaar more complicated than needed.

My question is however, is it safe to place data in the `href` as I'm showing below? I remember someone mentioning a potent ion problem concerning google spiders and the like.

**The PHP:**

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_pag_data)) { 
    echo "<a target='_blank' href='secondary_imgs.php?imgId=".$row['imgId']."'></a>";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use $(this) inside the function to reference the clicked gallery

```
$('.gallery').click(function(){
    $.get("secondary_imgs.php", { imgId: $(this).attr('value') });
});
```

Comment: I don't know if that would make any difference, as while `$(this)` is a shortcut, but using the whole selector would still work I think. I gave it a shot anyway, and it didn't make a difference.

Comment: It does make a difference.  Do you have firebug installed? If not install it and go to the console tab, refresh the page, and click a gallery link. See if any errors appear. You can also check the net tab after clicking the link.

Comment: Galen is correct.  $(this) makes a word of difference in the logic, it is not just a shortcut.  When you do $(selector).click(), you are binding each click event to each element the (selector) hits; when you use $(this), you are binding a specific click event to a specific element.  What you were doing initially was binding every click event to just the last element.

Comment: @Galen Sorry about that. Obviously I still have a lot to learn. I'll have to read up on that. I do have Firebug installed and tried what you did. Correct me if I'm wrong, but if an Ajax call is populating the page in the first place, and thus the links and the images, I have to include the above code inside the success of that Ajax call so it properly binds to the elements correct?

Comment: @Galen - I checked the Net tab and saw something interesting. It would seem that when I click on the link, `GET secondary_imgs.php` doesn't stop loading, which makes me suspect the data is not being sent. Does that makes sense to you?

Comment: If it doesn't stop loading it will never return to the calling page.  something in secondary_imgs.php is hanging. Post the code in that page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.gallery').click(function(){
    $.get("secondary_imgs.php", { imgId: $(this).attr('value') }, function(data) {
        $('body').append(data);
    });
});
```

If that does nothing when you click on it, browse to "/secondary_imgs.php?imgID=xxx" and see if it is returning the data correctly at all.

Comment: I tried your suggested code and it didn't seem to make a difference. Is what I'm doing even possible? Is Ajax the best way to do it?